# Move view to the top of the screen with animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I have following layout:

[image: layout]

Three `EditText`s in `LinearLayout` with `layout_width = 0.33`. When user put focus to one of those `EditText`s, two other should dissapear (maybe animation too) and last one should be moved to the top of the screen with some animation meanwhile soft keyboard is shown. Result should looke like this:

[image: result]

Solution without animation is simple:

```
if(focusedView == mBlueEdit) {
  mRedEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  mGreenEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I can't figure out, when to start (it's too late start it after GONE is set at other views) and how to compute X and Y positions at start and at the end of animation. Thanks in advance for every hint.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you are looking for, but you can create automatic animation by simply adding `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your LinearLayout.

Comment: Sadly, when other views' visibility is set to GONE no animation is displayed at all.

Comment: too bad... Was worth the try!